# Graphics with different dimensions

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to have two visualize the vectors $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$. Then, I wrote:

```
 Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}}]]
```

and

```
Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}]]
```

I didn't understand why they have different dimensions. Both should have the same length, no? The size which mathematica shows the graphics are arbitrary?

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To put them both in the same scale and graphic:

```
Show[Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 2}}]], 
     Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}]], 
     Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, I've already done this. What I didn't understand is why they have different dimensions if you don't use axes.

Comment: @user26832 Neither in Mathematica nor in mathematics you should infer anything about magnitudes without a scale

Comment: @user26832 Graphics objects in different figures are not comparable. The contents of each figure is scaled separately to fill out the frame and be viewable within the available screen space. To make the two lines comparable, put them in the same figure, no axes necessary.